# Cannot create instance of ViewModel when using Hilt DI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am not able to create an instance of hilt view model

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.testing.MainViewModel
```

I have provided all the necessary files below.

## Composable

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {}
```

## MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val initialName: String,
) : ViewModel() {
```

## module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideInitialName(): String = "ABCD"
}
```

## build.gradle file (root level)

```
plugins {
    ...

    // Dagger Hilt
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

## app level gradle file

```
plugins {
    ...

    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    ...
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk 34
       ...
    }
   
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    // Dagger-Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'


}
```

## Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class DOBApp: Application()
```

## Manifest

```
 android:name=".DOBApp"
```

I tried changing the version of dagger hilt and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Did you put @AndroidEntryPoint above your MainActivity?

Comment: Thanks @CodePoet. It worked. Stupid mistake I have done :)